# php move data from one form to another but with multiple input ids

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form where I set `textarea` field id by `for loop` using php

```
<?php
foreach ($restaurant as $rest_data) {
    ?>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="<?= 'comment_' . $rest_data->id ?>" id="<?= 'comment_' . $rest_data->id ?>" rows="3" placeholder="Leave a note for Restaurant (optional)" ></textarea>
    <?php
}
?>
```

but I need this field value in another form's hidden field with their respective ids using jQuery or any other method like php session or anything

Comment: then you need another $restaurant loop

Comment: @madalinivascu ok can you provide any sample ?

Comment: if you look very very closely in your question you can  see a loop, next to the textarea you can append a hidden input with your id or copy the code and replace the textarea with a hidden filed

Comment: The another form is on the same page?

Comment: @VijayRathore yes

Comment: Then you can run the same foreach loop in another form also. Just change the textarea to hidden field.

Comment: @VijayRathore but what about user entered value?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to create duplicate hidden elements for textarea fields of one form to another form . I would suggest you to bind events on keypress of the textarea and populate the value of textarea into hidden fields. 
1. Modify your code of generating textarea

```
<?php
foreach ($restaurant as $rest_data) {
    ?>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="<?= 'comment_' . $rest_data->id ?>" id="<?= 'comment_' . $rest_data->id ?>" rows="3" placeholder="Leave a note for Restaurant (optional)" onkeypress="fillInDuplicate(this)" ></textarea>
    <?php
}
?>
```

2. Create hidden fields in Another form

`<?php
  foreach ($restaurant as $rest_data) {
    ?>
  <inpupt type="hidden" name="<?= 'comment_' . $rest_data->id.'-hidden' ?>" id="<?= 'comment_' . $rest_data->id.'_hidden' ?>" />
  <?php
 }
 ?>`

3. Write a simple javascript , which will duplicate the data from textarea  to hidden input field .

`function fillInDuplicate(element){
   document.getElementById(element.id+'_hidden').value = element.value;
}`

I hope this helped.

Comment: Your question is still not clear, What error is coming?

Comment: by the way I have modified your query based on my requirement, useful one

Answer (score 0):

save textarea value in Session and then save this in hidden field and on submission get this value where u submit your form or get this value anywhere...

```
<input type="hidden" id="comment_id" name="comment_id" value="<?=$SESSION['comment_id']?>">
```

Comment: u think hidden field is secure @umer best

Comment: use form method post. @kunal

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field for each textarea

```
  $('textarea[name^="comment"]').each(function(i,v){
      $('#main-form').append('<input type="hidden" id="comment_id" name="comment_id" value="'+$(v).attr('id')+'">');
  });
```

Trigger this code when you click the button to open the `#main-form`

Comment: but how can i get the user entered value in another form's hidden field ?

Comment: so you want the content of the textarea into a hidden field in another form?

Comment: yes, whateva user has entered i need it on another form

Comment: you will need some javascript for that, can you post the second form, how is the second form related to this one?

Comment: yes with jquery i am setting all other values in hidden field except this because of multiple field, actually this form pops up when user click on button

Comment: so you want all the textareas in a hidden field or in individual fields?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155386/discussion-between-arsee-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this you can set textarea with id and value using this

```
<?php for($i = 0;$i <= 10;$i++){ ?>
<input type="hidden" name="counterarray[]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
<textarea name="data<?php echo $i; ?>" id="myid<?php echo $i; ?>"></textarea> <?php } ?>
```

Then,

While in the hidden part you can use counterarray to loop to same textarea ..Correct me if you need anything else.